# Asterisk extensions.conf confusion

Tags: voip, asterisk

Hopefully someone out there has an answer, but I have a couple lines in an existing configuration I need to fix and with a somewhat weak understanding of how Asterisk works.

First off, I have a department that wants to have all of their phones ring at the same time when a caller comes in and chooses to contact this department (customer service).  So far, no problem.

example:

exten => 12000,1,Dial(SIP/13227&SIP/11205&SIP/11216&SIP/11220&SIP/11237&SIP/11241&SIP/11244&SIP/11258&SIP/11260&SIP/11267&SIP/11272&SIP/11285&SIP/11291&SIP/11299,30,rwW)

However, now I have a problem since I have some people working remotely for this department.  How can I tell Asterisk to dial his personal phone number at the same time as these internal extensions? So far all I have to work with on 'how' to dial to a personal phone number is this example:

exten => 11229,1,Dial(Local/*(PHONE NUMBER)*@internal||Wmorg)

Is it possible to add the second line for dialing to an external number to the line for internal numbers?  Or could I simply create two lines with the same priority so that Asterisk will read the two lines and determine that they should be done at the same time?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reach out to Asterisk support and they concluded that if I place two lines with the same priority in the configuration that this would cause a problem and result in one of the lines not working.  They followed up by saying that it is acceptable to use the following to dial internal numbers at the same time as internal numbers:

exten => 12000,1,Dial(SIP/13227&local(PHONE NUMBER)@internal||Wmorg/11285&SIP/11291&SIP/11299,30,rwW)

But it turns out it looks like this post was for naught, as using XLite is probably the best option in my situation as it will circumvent long distance calls.